# Dynamically assign master/slave variables in Ansible role

Tags: linux, architecture, ansible, mariadb, devops

I have a simple mariadb role which permits to setup master/slave replication on two servers. In order to do this, I have to define in my inventory my 2 nodes like this:

```
node1 master=true 
node2 slave=true
```

This way, I can setup one role to setup master/slave replication using Ansible when statement playing with this vars.

```
- name: Setup master conf
  template: >-
    src="templates/master.conf.j2"
    dest="{{ master_config_file }}"
  when:
    - master is defined
```

Now, I would like to get something more automatic that could dynamically and randomly assign a master variable to one node, and slave variable to all other nodes.

I have seen some Ansible doc about variables and filters, but none of them seems to be adapted to that. I guess that I have to develop my own Ansible variable plugin to do that.

Comment: "Random" is an enemy of automation. Define predictable idempotent rule and follow it (I'm almost sure that it can be done with standard filters/operators and no development is required).

Comment: By random, I mean choose randomly a master server in the list of nodes. This way, when I spawn my VMs, none of them are specialized. I would like them to automatically become specialized with my first Ansible run. Thanks for the reply, I will look again at existing Ansible filters and implement one if I can't find what I want.

Comment: And what's on playbook re-run?

Comment: For now, I register a variable firstrun_slave firstrun_master to avoid re-configuration replication during replay

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise [facts.d](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d). Something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - file:
        path: /etc/ansible/facts.d
        state: directory
    - shell: echo '{{ my_facts | to_json }}' > /etc/ansible/facts.d/role.fact
      args:
        creates: /etc/ansible/facts.d/role.fact
      vars:
        my_facts:
          is_master: "{{ true if play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) == 0 else false }}"
      register: role_fact
    # refresh facts if fact has been just added
    - setup:
      when: role_fact | changed
    - set_fact:
        is_master: "{{ ansible_local.role.is_master }}"
    - debug:
        var: is_master
```

This will create `role.fact` on remote nodes if it is not there and use `is_master` fact from it. During subsequent runs `ansible_local.role.is_master` is fetched automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic group to do that. Another use case : You don't know which node is the master because it is elected, and you need to performs actions only on master.

To use a dynamic group, you need to define two pays in your playbook :

- First one in order to determine which node is the master and add it in a dynamic group, you need to use a command
- Then execute tasks on master, slaves

Following playbook determine which nodes are masters and slaves and execute a play on each types :

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - shell: <command on node to retrieve node type>
    register: result__node_type
  - name: If node is a master, add it in masters group
    add_host:
      name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      groups: temp_master
    when: result__node_type.stdout == "MASTER"
  - name: If node is a slave, add it in slaves group
    add_host:
      name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      groups: temp_slave
    when: result__node_type.stdout == "SLAVE"
  - name: No master found, then assign first one (or random if you want) to masters group
    add_host:
      name: "groups['all'][0]"
      groups: temp_master
    run_once: yes
    when: groups['temp_master'] | length == 0
  - name: No slave found, then assign others to slaves group
    add_host:
      name: "groups['all'][0]"
      groups: temp_slave
    run_once: yes
    with_items: "{{ groups['all'][1:] }}"
    when: groups['temp_slave'] | length == 0

- hosts: temp_master
  gather_facts: false
    tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "Action on master {{ ansible_host }}"

- hosts: temp_slave
  gather_facts: false
    tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "Action on slave {{ ansible_host }}"
```